# How can we use Junit test without eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have wrote a piece of code in Junit. I need to run it without eclipse. Any suggestions how can I do that ?

Comment: which version of Junit you are using ?

Comment: junit version 4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have an option to run your test cases in command line,

**Example**:

As you are running the mvn clean install for building your application, 
In the same way, you can also run your test cases as well by using the command.

```
1. Command to compile your test class >> **javac -cp junit-4.12.jar;. UserDAOTest.java ProductDAOTest.java** --> general command is >> **javac -cp <junit-jar-file>;. TestClass1.java TestClass2.java**
2. Run the test cases >> ** java -cp <junit-jar>;<hamcrest-jar>;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  TestClass1 TestClass2 **
3. Running the unit test cases by Maven Command Line >> mvn test >> mvn clean test >> mvn clean compile test
```

Comment: Hello, I want to use command line but not maven? I'm not getting a clear of how will it work?

Comment: java -cp Z:\Job\Resumes\Swati\Selenium\AccessHQAssignment\TripPlanner\lib\junit-4.12.jar;Z:\Job\Resumes\Swati\Selenium\AccessHQAssignment\TripPlanner\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;. TripPlannerJUnit
Error: Could not find or load main class TripPlannerJUnit
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TripPlannerJUnit                     
            The command doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse 2018-09 in *Java Application* and *JUnit* **launch configurations** there is a button ***Show Command Line*** for that.

See also: [video that shows this feature in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW6VRX1lqk0&t=71s)

Comment: Hi. Thanks tried it. However, it is giving me all the paths in my local desktop. And i need to share this piece of code with someone else. There are too many files to be shared? Any way out to this??

Comment: @SSharma All these JARs on the classpath are not Eclipse-specific and required to run the tests. But you can copy all the JARs into the same folder (e. g. `lib`) and then use in the classpath the wildcard `*` instead of listing them all (e. g. `lib/*`). If you use Gradle or Maven you only have to share the dependencies (`build.gradle`/`pom.xml`) and Gradle/Maven will download all these JARs automatically.

Comment: Hi. Not using maven on the other system that means I'll have to share all the jar files. Also, using the command line functionality, it gave me one single line. How would I execute this (complied and run) on other system command line ? Sorry but I'm new to this hence asking ..

Comment: @SSharma If you want to do it manually, you have to copy all the resources that are referenced in the command line call to the other system. Collect them into a folder and adapt the command line call to use relative references. Gradle or Maven provides a so-called wrapper for that: a small JAR that is part of a project together with the source code and which downloads Gradle/Maven if it is not installed on the system and then all required dependencies that are specified in the `build.gradle`/`pom.xml`.

Comment: @SSharma For example, if you want to build JUnit 4 (which uses Maven) or JUnit 5 (which uses Gradle) from source code yourself, download the project from GitHub and just run [`mvnw`(`.bat`)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4) or [`gradlew`(`.bat`)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5). The only requirements are that a Java JDK with the minimum version number is installed and that there is an internet connection.

Comment: I understand that I need to keep all resources in a folder and share. The person I'm sharing this task is not willing on using Maven/ gradle at all. So it has to be run using command line. Hence, I was asking what commands I need to execute to make the code run for example any specific commands to compile or run the Junit code? Or should I simply copy the single liner i got from eclipse to linux/command prompt and with all the jars stored locally it would run??

Comment: @SSharma If you also want to compile the source code (sharing the `.java` instead of the compiled `.class` files), you have to run `javac` (which requires a JDK and not only a JRE) with the same `-classpath`/`-cp` as to run it to compile the source code from the source folder (by default `src`) to the output folder (by default `bin`) before running it.

Comment: This is the single liner I'm talking about. Placed all files under "Z:\lib\*". The code is under TripPlannerJUnit.java. Would I need to create package - com.example.tests.TripPlannerJUnit as well???  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe -ea -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "Z:\lib\*" org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 61650 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.example.tests.TripPlannerJUnit