# How to run a .java file created in Eclipse on windows command prompt with java cmd?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, command-line

I have created a project for school that runs properly in eclipse but, due to strict submission guidelines, must be able to run on command line in the format "java project_name". I have been able to run it with "java -jar project_name.jar", after exporting it to JAR, but this is not allowed. How do I format my project in order to run it with the java cmd?

Comment: Have you tried using javac command? The instructor may be looking for the compiled version.

Comment: Are you allowed to class the class files directly? If not then the only way is to write a wrapper .cmd file which invokes the jar. Otherwise there is the new single-file source feature introduced in Java 11 (I believe) which allows you to run your code without compiling.

Comment: @CoderLee I'm getting a 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command error when I try so might be a different issue all together... I redefined the path in environment variables to no luck, I suppose I should create a new question for that issue

Comment: @AdamTamargo you might want to try removing then reinstalling Java, I have had a similar problem before and that fixed it.

Comment: @CoderLee I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514435/6505250

Answer (score 0):

1. Compile all your source code files with javac. If you can run your project in Eclipse, your source files are compiled already. So find them in your Eclipse project folder all those files which end in .class ( It is in a folder named "bin" if I remember correctly).
2. Make sure that all those compiled .class files are in the same folder, or have the same root folder if your project consists of multiple packages.
3. Use cd to change your current directory to that folder
4. Run your project with : java MainClassName (just the main class name, without .class ! )

P/s: On your problem with "javac", install a program called Everything. Then search for the location of javac and copy its path to the PATH variable.

Comment: For 2: They don't need to the same folder. This should obey `package` sentence in the source. Besides, I am surprised that you have 1 silver badge with **no** bronze badge!

Comment: I think it is a bug. I certainly created this account less than 30 days ago. Actually I have another account and I created this accidentally on uni computer. You are correct. I should have mentioned that too.

Comment: I figured it out. Had to download a newer version of jdk and configure it to get it working. Thank you for the help.